# jQuery not work correctly, after a submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with a jQuery,the problem is when i do the submit, when i press the button, the website dosen't stay on the same html page but switch to the "insert.php" page, to avoid that in the script, as you can see I put a return false "$("#myForm").submit(function(){ return false;});" but that does not work.
Here it is the html form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
            PERSONE:
            <select id="persona" name="perselect">
                <!-- these option come from the database by a jquery --> 
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
    <br>
            AUTO:
            <select id="auto" name="autselect">
                <!-- these option come from the database by a jquery --> 
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
    <br><br>


        INIZIO:<br>
        Ora:
        <select id="oraInizio" name="oraInizio">
            <option value="00">00</option>
            <!-- all the hours -->
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        Minuto:
        <select id="minutoInizio" name="minutoInizio">
            <option value="00">00</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="45">45</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Data:
        <input type="Date" name="dataInizio"/><br>

        <br><br>


        FINE:<br>
        Ora:
        <select id="oraFine" name="oraFine">
            <option value="00">00</option>
            <!-- all the hours -->
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        Minuto:
        <select id="minutoFine" name="minutoFine">
            <option value="00">00</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="45">45</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        Data:
        <input type="Date" name="dataFine"/><br>

        <br><br>

        Note:<br>
        <input type="text" name="note"><br>
        <button id="sub">salva</button>
        <!--<input type="submit"/>-->

        <span id="result"></span>
```

And This is the script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fetchData(); 
});

$("#sub").click(function(){

   var data = $("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), data, function(info){ 
  $("#result").html(info); });
  });

 $("#myForm").submit(function(){ 
   return false;
 });

 function fetchData()
 {
        var personeOp;
        $.getJSON("fetchPersona.php", function(data){
        $.each(data.result, function(i,persona){
        personeOp +="<option value='"
        +persona.id+
        "'>"
        +persona.nome+" "+persona.cognome+
        "</option>";
    });
    $('#persona').html(personeOp);
});

    var autoOp;
    $.getJSON("fetchAuto.php", function(data){
    $.each(data.result, function(i,auto){
    autoOp +="<option value='"
    +auto.id+
    "'>"
    +auto.nome+
    "</option>";
    }); 
    $('#auto').html(autoOp);
});
```

}

Comment: It's outside the `$("#sub").click(){}`. What about the scenario when form is send using Enter key?

Comment: If you don't want to submit the `form`, then firstly don't use a button of type submit (default one). So use instead: `<button id="sub" type="button">salva</button>`

Comment: Well if you're changing the submit button to being a button, why even provide an action on the form?

Comment: @MattFletcher It is used here to send the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the submit handler inside a click handler, so it won't start listening for submit events until you've clicked once.

If you move this code:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){ 
   return false;
 });
```

...outside of the click handler, it should work.

I'd also recommend a slight change to how you do it:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Actually, I may need to delete this answer as I've just realised that the code formatting of the question possibly mislead me. Still not entirely sure...

Comment: The code you suggest to move it's alredy outside the click handler, but i notice a thing if I put the code $(#"myForm.... after of before the click handler the result changes

Comment: Hm, yes. I think that's because of the `return false`. Does it work if you change to my `e.preventDefault()` suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the callback function for the click in the callback function for the submit and add a preventDefault on event on the submit callback. Also, try to format your code before posting:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
  $.post( $(this).attr("action"), data, function(info){ 
    $("#result").html(info); 
  });

});
```

Comment: I try to apply your solution but it still go to the insert.php pageto eco ther result...

Comment: maybe you have some js errors that prevent the script to execute and prevent the normal form to submit.